# Extract only value from bins

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

```
sentence
15
4
17
110
```

This is the code I am using to get the bins

```
    category = ['1-12','13-24','25-36','37-48','48-60','61-72','73-84','85-96','97-108','109-128']
    df['len_sentence'] = category
    bins = [1,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,128]
    groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.sentence, bins))
    print(groups.count().sentence)
    df['distribuition_len_sentence'] = groups.count().sentence
```

This is the output I am getting when I do print `print(groups.count().sentence)`.

```
length_sentence
    (1, 12]        175
    (12, 24]       797
    (24, 36]      2096
    (36, 48]      2416
    (48, 60]       944
    (60, 72]      2543
    (72, 84]      4394
    (84, 96]      5054
    (96, 108]      637
    (108, 128]     199
```

But when I add it to a new columns in a new csv `df['distribuition_len_sentence'] = groups.count().sentence`. This is what I get

```
    len_sentence    distribuition_len_sentence
1   1-12    NaN
2   13-24   NaN
3   25-36   NaN
4   37-48   NaN
5   48-60   NaN
6   61-72   NaN
7   73-84   NaN
8   85-96   NaN
9   97-108  NaN
10  109-128     NaN
```

I just want to get the value of these bins, example 175, 797 etc. I do not want the bin. How do I extract the value?

Comment: what is the logic for getting output?

Comment: @user1740577 added the logic

Comment: I can't run your code, please send code that we can run correctly. send the sample of your problem NOT pieces of your code